# Is there a way to automate Power BI data source import from s3 stored CSV but each time file name will be different?

Tags: csv, amazon-s3, powerbi, powerbi-embedded, powerbi-datasource

My issue is this, in my organization, we create a CSV file with some analytical data every 10 minutes to a new file in a s3 bucket.The naming convention is this,

```
"some_table_name  date_and_time.csv"
```

So basically every 10 minutes, a new file is created. I've already setup a visualization and data transform steps to work with a csv file of the format we'd generate. What I don't understand is how to automatically refresh this thing, but with each refresh, power bi should pull the new csv file, discarding old ones. I already understand to do this with the same file, but how can do it with new files each time.

appreciate any help and sorry if my question is too long as my English is a little weak.

Comment: Can you update your question with the PowerQuery code to pull in the one CSV. Only the `Source` part, not the transformation of the CSV itself.

Comment: Refer to this Microsoft Community Power BI forum discussion.
https://community.fabric.microsoft.com/t5/Power-Query/Can-I-connect-to-a-Amazon-S3-bucket-using-Power-Query/td-p/111919

Please let me know if the issue still persists.